# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'java.lang.Integer' does not have the property '0'

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jstl, spring-webflow

I'm try show my data into JSP using JSTL, but console show me `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'java.lang.Integer' does not have the property '0'` I have a `List<Object>` with `Integer and BigDecimal` and my JSP I did put

```
<c:forEach items="${obj}" var="object">
   <tr>
      <td width="10%" class="r1Left">${object[0].id}</td>
   </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

My `List<Object>` contain [10, 1278612143.23, 10, 3343443.56, 4, 123.45]

Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

I think you just want `${object.id}`, you are getting the object not the list at this point.

Comment: You definitely don't want the `[0]`. The JSTL `foreach` tag makes the `var` object be a single object, not the List itself. Once you removed that, you should have at least gotten a different error. But if the objects in the List are Integers, `.id` isn't going to work since Integer has no `id` property (no `getId()` method).

Comment: maybe you just want ${object}